# How do I pass a file path with spaces as an argument in FFmpeg/cmd via python?

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg

Basically the code below is taking wav files saved in a folder location `ufolder`, and trimming them to one minute clips and saving those clips in a new folder `dfolder`. I'm using python, cmd, and ffmpeg to do this.

The problem is that the original folder location has spaces in it, so I get an error which reads: `W:\ARCHIVESNAS1\INGEST\01: No such file or directory`

If I were to use cmd directly, I would circumvent this problem with quotes.

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i "W:\ARCHIVESNAS1\INGEST\01 PLEASE REVIEW\Levy\GeorgeBloodShipments\_6-Ready-for-Ingest\SREDReels20210805\26368\data" "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\practice"
```

How do I include quotes with a command that's using variables. Adding quotes, as I do immediately below, doesn't work.

```py
os.system("ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i **"{0}" "{1}"**".format(filepathO, filepathN))
```

```py
import os
ufolder = r'W:\ARCHIVESNAS1\INGEST\01 PLEASE REVIEW\Levy\GeorgeBloodShipments\_6-Ready-for-Ingest\SREDReels20210805\26368\data'
dfolder = r'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\practice'
for filename in os.listdir(ufolder):
    if (filename.endswith(".wav")): #or .avi, .mpeg, whatever.
        filepathO = str(ufolder)+"\\"+str(filename)
        filepathN = str(dfolder)+"\\"+"CLIPPED"+str(filename)
        os.system("ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i {0} {1}".format(filepathO, filepathN))
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), then each argument can contain spaces and other special character, python will handle it correctly. Like e. g. `subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-ss", "0", "-t", "10", "-i", filepath0, filepathN])` instead of `os.system(`... no matter if you are in windows or linux etc.

Comment: If you really want to use `os.system()`, use `shlex.quote()` to quote arguments.

Comment: @Barmar, is `shlex.quote()` correct for Windows? I thought it was only for POSIXy shells; cmd.exe's quoting rules (and those used by the windows libc to assemble the string the operating system passes a process into an argv array when a Windows program doesn't choose to override that and parse the command line itself) are very different.

Comment: @AtBay,..._really_, follow BitLauncher's advice here. It doesn't work for every possible Windows program, but it'll work fine for ones that don't do weird Windows-only things; and ffmpeg is natively UNIX software, so it's definitely not going out of its way to add nonportable weirdness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't check, I assumed (hoped?) that it would be cross-platform.